# Perl CGI redirect after cancelling on a 401

Tags: perl, http, http-headers, cgi

I've currently got a small script running that sends a 401 to the client, upon cancelling and not providing user details the script will return nothing.

I'd like to send a redirect to the page they have come from instead.

The main subroutine looks like this;

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;

sub checkAuth {
  my ($user, $pass) = &getAuthUsers(); # Get the user and pass of already authenticated users.
  unless ($user) {
    &sendAuthenticationHeader(); # Send 401
  }

  # Check user against DB and return 1 for success.
  if ( &checkUser($user, $pass) eq 'Y') { return 1 };
  else { # This is the redirect I'm trying to issue.
    my $cgi = CGI->new();
    print $cgi->redirect($ENV{HTTP_REFERER}); # Redirect to the referer url
    exit;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately whenever I try to send new headers it's just received as plain text.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only send one header! You can't return both a 401 and a 302 (redirect). You could use an "http-equiv" or JS to get the browser to redirect, but why just return the 302?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendAuthenticationHeader()` emits a header with a 401 status code.

`print $cgi->redirect($ENV{HTTP_REFERER});` emits a header with a 302 status code. Of course, since you've already emitted a header, this gets treated as the body.

There's no point to return a 401 if you want to redirect. Change your code to

```
sub checkAuth {
  my ($user, $pass) = getAuthUsers();

  if (!$user || !checkUser($user, $pass)) {
    print CGI::redirect($ENV{HTTP_REFERER});
    exit;
  }
}
```

Notes:

- Removed incorrect `&`. Don't tell Perl to ignore the prototype of subs. Address the underlying issue instead if required.
- The return value of `checkUser` is boolean, so it should return either a true or a false value (e.g. `0` or `1`), not two true values (e.g. `N` or `Y`). The above code assumed you fixed this.

Comment: Ahh I getcha, just implemented it.
Thanks a bunch ikegami.